# Erro ao recuperar informações do json com ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu estou fazendo uma requisição JSON, que me retorna os resultados, mas não no data, mas sim no error do ajax.

```
 var url = window.location;
var id = url.toString().split("=")[1];
var msg = '';
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'load-data.php?id='+id,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
         msg = data;
         alert(msg)

    },
    error:function(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
});
```

Como podem reparar embaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só não entendo porque o resultado aparece no error do ajax.

Comment: Você precisa olhar no console e saber saber qual é o status que está sendo retornado.

Comment: 200, se for o status da pag, que é um ok

Comment: Confere se o tipo de data ajax tá assim; `dataType: "json"`

Comment: sim, está sim Leonardo

Comment: Porque diz que o resultado está no erro? Vejo em `responseText`!

Comment: Já tentou utilizar outros tipos para ver se tem algum efeito diferente? Você pode utilizar `text json` ou apenas  `text`

Comment: No text, falando verdade, deu certo

Comment: E no text json, mesma coisa do erro

Comment: Como está o retorno do seu PHP ?

Comment: Do um echo json_encode em uma função de select

Comment: Vou deixar o dataType : "text" mesmo, deu certo